# R: Melt dataframe by 1 column and stack the other columns that have the same name patterns

Tags: r, merge, reshape, melt, data-transform

I have this simplified data situation:

```
df <- data.frame(Year = 1:3,
                 A.x = 4:6,
                 A.y = 7:9,
                 A.z = 10:12,
                 B.x = 4:6,
                 B.y = 7:9,
                 B.z = 10:12,
                 C.x = 4:6,
                 C.y = 7:9,
                 C.z = 10:12)
```

My goal is this:

[image: image.png]

```
df_goal <- data.frame(Year = rep(1:3, each = 3),
                 x = rep(4:6, each = 3),
                 y = rep(7:9, each = 3),
                 z = rep(10:12, each = 3))
```

Please note that these values are arbitrary, only the column names, pattern, and the order of the target Year matter.

I tried to create the target dataframe "manually", e.g.: column *i* contains values from positions *x* to *z* of the original data set. But it looks really clumsy since the data I'm dealing with is huge. Are there better ways to reshape the data more systematically?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `pivot_longer`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
 df %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -Year, names_to = ".value", 
      names_pattern = "^[^.]+\\.(.*)")

# A tibble: 9 × 4
   Year     x     y     z
  <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     4     7    10
2     1     4     7    10
3     1     4     7    10
4     2     5     8    11
5     2     5     8    11
6     2     5     8    11
7     3     6     9    12
8     3     6     9    12
9     3     6     9    12
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's what I need. Could you please also show me what should be the regular expression if the column names go like this: aB_1_1, aB_1_2,...aB_1_6, aB_2_1, aB_2_2..., aB_12_6?

Comment: @Theodore what would be the column you need as output.  If you want to get the lower case 'a' as column `names_pattern = "^([a-z])[A-Z]_.*"`. if it is both aB, then do you need to capture `"^([a-z][A-Z])_.*"`

Comment: I need to capture them both, also with the digits that come after, just like in the example. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @Theodore do you want `aB_1`, `aB_2` as column names?? then do `names_pattern = "^([a-z][A-Z]_\\d+)_\\d+"`

Comment: Yes, you're amazing! I can finally go to sleep now. Many thanks ^^

Comment: Just one more question out of curiosity, Sir. What if I want to capture `aB_..._1`, `aB_..._2`, `aB_..._3`, `aB_..._4`, `aB_..._5`, `aB_..._6` (only the last digit)?

Comment: Do you want aB1, aB2, ... Or if you want only the last digit/s `".*_(\\d+)$"`

Comment: aB_..._1, aB_..._2, aB_..._3, aB_..._4, aB_..._5, aB_..._6

Comment: Sorry. Let me type again

Comment: Sorry your question is not clear.  Your were inputting the same input as before

Comment: can you show what columns you expect as output

Comment: Column name (either is fine, I can change latter. I only care about the values):
aB_..._1, aB_..._2, aB_..._3, aB_..._4, aB_..._5, aB_..._6
or
aB_1, aB_2, aB_3, aB_4, aB_5, aB_6

Value:
aB_1_1, aB_2_2, aB_1_3, aB_1_4, aB_1_5, aB_1_6
aB_2_1, aB_2_2, aB_2_3, aB_2_4, aB_2_5, aB_2_6
aB_3_1, aB_3_2, aB_3_3, aB_3_4, aB_3_5, aB_3_6
....
aB_12_1, aB_12_2, aB_12_3, aB_12_4, aB_12_5, aB_12_6

Comment: In the output, what would be column names i.e. if your input column is `aB_3_6` do you expect `aB6` as column name

Comment: Values: 
`aB_1_1, aB_2_2, aB_1_3, aB_1_4, aB_1_5, aB_1_6//
aB_2_1, aB_2_2, aB_2_3, aB_2_4, aB_2_5, aB_2_6//
aB_3_1, aB_3_2, aB_3_3, aB_3_4, aB_3_5, aB_3_6//
....//
aB_12_1, aB_12_2, aB_12_3, aB_12_4, aB_12_5, aB_12_6`

Sorry, it's not easy to type properly in this mini chat. I want to have 6 columns corresponding to the last digit (from 1 to 6). The positions of values for each column are shown above

Comment: Try something like `df %>% rename_with(~ str_replace(., "^([^_]+)(_\\d+)_(\\d+)$", "\\1\\3\\2"), -Year) %>% pivot_longer(cols = -Year, names_to = ".value", names_pattern = "^([^_]+)_.*")`

Comment: Yes, you're right

Comment: i.e. base don the same data you showed, if i change the column names to `names(df)[-1] <- c("aB_1_1", "aB_2_1", "aB_1_2", "aB_2_2", "aB_3_2", "aB_4_2", "aB_1_3", "aB_2_3", "aB_3_3")`

Comment: i have to leave now.  thanks

Comment: That's perfect. You're the best! Thank you for being patient with a newbie like me :D